# The use of "respingada"

Tags: definiciones

I encountered this word and looked it up on the RAE dictionary.

It doesn't appear in the dictionary, I have found it nowhere as "respingad**o**" either.

But I have seen it in sentences, where it seems to describe the shape of a nose.

Is this actually a real word or just slang? And why would a single word exist where its function only seems to be to describe the shape of a nose?

Thank you.

Comment: Where did you "encounter" the word? It could be slang.

Answer (score 1):

In Colombia it is very common to say «respingada» to describe a kind/shape of nose.

The verb «respingar» means «levantado, hacia arriba» (pointing up) and that is why in Colombia we calle a pointing up nose «una nariz respingada» and for most people it is synonym of beauty.

We call a big nose that points down «nariz aguileña» because it resemblance the beak of a raptor bird.

Most plastic esthetic surgeries (Rhinoplasty) around here are aimed to change a big pointing down nose into a «nariz respingada» like Angelina Jolie or Jennifer Aniston's.

[image]

I did a quick search on the internet and I saw the expression is used in many places in hispanoamerica.

Comment: Confirmed for México

Answer (score 0):

*Respingado* is a participle. The search for the verb *[respingar](https://dle.rae.es/respingar)* gives this result:

> respingar
> Del lat. *repedināre, de repedāre 'recular'.
>
> 1. intr. Dicho de una bestia: Sacudirse y gruñir porque le lastima o molesta algo o le hace cosquillas.
> 2. intr. coloq. Dicho del borde de la falda o de la chaqueta: Elevarse por estar mal hecha o mal colocada la prenda.
> 3. intr. coloq. Resistir, repugnar, hacer gruñendo lo que se manda.

In any case, none of the definitions refers to the type of nose, where the term used in the RAE is *[respingona](https://dle.rae.es/resping%C3%B3n?m=form)*

> respingón, na
>
> 1. adj. coloq. Dicho especialmente de una parte del cuerpo: Levantada hacia arriba. Culo respingón. Nariz respingona.
> 2. adj. Méx. protestón.

The use of the word *respingada* in reference to the type of nose is mostly in Latin America, possibly by mistake or localism.

Comment: *Respingada* is a not really a mistake; it makes perfect sense as a figurative use of meaning #2 of *respingar* according to the DLE.

Answer (score 0):

El verbo a que te refieres es "respingar". Lo puedes encontrar en;

https://dle.rae.es/respingar

Dice;

Del lat. *repedināre, de repedāre 'recular'.

1. intr. Dicho de una bestia: Sacudirse y gruñir porque le lastima o molesta algo o le hace cosquillas.
2. intr. coloq. Dicho del borde de la falda o de la chaqueta: Elevarse por estar mal hecha o mal colocada la prenda.
3. intr. coloq. Resistir, repugnar, hacer gruñendo lo que se manda.

---

Este vocablo es de uso obsoleto, se define que esta levantado, alzado, aupado, alto, izado, elevado, subido y encaramado hacia la parte de arriba o que esta ascendido o empinado en la parte muy elevada o alta en un lugar o sitio. Nariz respingona.

También se dice de personas propensas a ser altivas que miran por encima del hombro.

Espero te haya servido. Saludos.

Diego M.